# Get text from <strong> Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to get the text which is after the < strong > (in this case "1. 95183645") into a variable with Selenium.

[image]

I've already tried with:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath").text`
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath").text()`
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath").getText`
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath").getText()`
but nothing seems to work.

Thanks

Comment: What XPath have you tried? What do you mean it doesn't work? Is it giving you an output you don't expect, is it giving you an error? Why did you try ```getText``` and ```getText()```?

Comment: .text is the only one that should work if you have to right xpath.

Comment: //table[@id='backupcodes_table']/tbody/tr[1]/td/strong is most likely the right xpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='backupcodes_table']//strong").text
```